# mysql query using condition inside sum

Tags: mysql

I have a column  (****Purchasetype****), userid in video table **purchasetype** is some how containg values  0,1, 2,3,4,.. etc. I want two sum these value order by `userid`.

For ex: `sum ( purchasetype )  order by userid` but I want like this

```
if purchasetype= 0  then its value is 0.99
if purchasetype =1 or 20  then its value is 3.99
if purchasetype = 3 or 13or 22  then its value is 9.99
```

so on. Below is complete list

```
0 ,17= 0.99
1,20=3.99
2=6.99
3,13,22=9.99
4,5,6,7,8,,10,11,12=0.00
14=19.99
15,23=39.99
16,24=59.99
18,21=01.99
19=02.99
else
19.99
```

i want to sum all the values of `purchasetype` with their replaced values (given above) `order by userid`

do we can put condition inside the `sum()` function of mysql; If its possible then please give  me solution , may be this will solve my problem

Answer (score 4):

You would use the aggregate function `SUM()` and `CASE`:

```
select 
  SUM(CASE purchaseType
        WHEN 0 or 17 THEN 0.99
        WHEN 1 or 20 THEN 3.99
        WHEN 3 or 13 or 22 THEN 9.99 
        WHEN 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 or 10 or 11 or 12 THEN 0
        WHEN 14 THEN 19.99
        WHEN 15 or 23 THEN 39.99
        WHEN 16 or 24 THEN 59.99
        WHEN 18 or 21 THEN 1.99
        WHEN 19 THEN 2.99
        ELSE 19.99 END) as Total
from yourTable
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8716/3)

Comment: @user1648175 glad it is working. if an answer helped you then be sure to mark it as accepted via the checkmark on the left. It will help future visitors as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to create table `ptPrices`:

```
create table ptPrices (Purchasetype int, Price float);
insert into ptPrices values (0,0.99);
insert into ptPrices values (1,3.99);
....
insert into ptPrices values (19,2.99);
```

And then use this query:

```
select sum(isnull(ptPrices.Price,19.99)) from Table 
left join ptPrices 
    on Table.Purchasetype=ptPrices.Purchasetype;
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesn't use SUM from MySQL query, the logic will get the job done

```
    $query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM video");
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
         //Then set conditionals 
         if($row['purchase_type)==0 || $row['purchase_type)==17){
              $values[] = 0.99;
             //Then your mysqli_query here

           }
    elseif($row['purchase_type)==1 || $row['purchase_type)==20){
           $values[]= 3.99;           

           }
    elseif//Blah blah for all values
         }
//After exhausting all the rows, add the SUM
$sum = array_sum($values); //$sum will be equal to the addition of all the vlues of the //array $values
```